# how to use my own EDI template class for conversion from EDI to XML using EDIfabric?

Tags: c#, edi, edifabric

EDIfarbic uses its own POCO class for reading and converting EDI file to intermediate data, I want my own POCO class to replace theirs, for example, they are using TS850 class for converting x12 850 EDI file to XML,but i want to use my own class format X12_00401_850.
here is the code that is using TS850 class for conversion:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\custom-schema.xsd", FileMode.Open))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TS850), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006");
            var xmlDataWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };
            using (var ediReader = new X12Reader(File.OpenRead("C:\\Users\\850.edi"), "EdiFabric.Templates.X12"))
            {
                var ediItems = ediReader.ReadToEnd().ToList();
                var transactions = ediItems.OfType<TS850>();
                foreach (var transaction in transactions)
                {
                   
                    serializer.Serialize(XmlWriter.Create(File.Create("C:\\Users\\output.xml"), xmlDataWriterSettings), transaction);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("file is made");
            }
        }

    }
```

I tried to change the type from TS850 to my class, but it didn't work. The only option I have is to map the TS850 class to my class, but is there any other way where it could directly be converted?